# How to compare MySQL database schemas

Tags: mysql, schema

I am looking for a tool that will allow me to compare schemas of MySQL databases.
 Which is the best tool to do that?

Comment: Redgate MySQL Compare is such a tool. This has recently been released for free for non-commercial purposes. The serial key will be emailed to you following download. Enjoy!

Comment: For [mysql schemas comparison](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/schemacompare/) and sync you can use dbForge Schema Compare for MySQL or dbForge Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Navicat is able to do that for you.  It will also synchronize schema and/or data between two mysql database instances.  I've used it with success in the past.

[Link](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql)

There is a screenshot of the data and structure synchronization tool here:

http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_mysql/mysql_detail_mac.html#7

Comment: i do wont to syn i wont frest just to comaper and see the different

Comment: you can compare before executing anything

Comment: Both links are broken.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps a bit late to the party, but I've just written a simple tool in PHP to compare MySQL database schemas:

[PHP script to compare MySQL database schemas](https://github.com/joefreeman/dbdiff)
[How to use the script](https://web.archive.org/web/20160203150852/http://joef.co.uk/blog/2009/07/php-script-to-compare-mysql-database-schemas)

It exports the schema and serialises it before doing the comparison. This is so that databases can be compared that reside on different hosts (where both hosts may not be accessible by the PHP script).

**Edit:**

[Python Script](https://github.com/cj203/compare_mysql/blob/master/schema_diference.py)

Comment: a nice & clean solution. it would be great if the script can memorize the schema instead of requiring user to copy & paste the schema

Comment: I modified it to do a mysqldump pf the schemas, then load them. That works... :) No more cut and paste

Comment: The link mentioned above is not working getting not found error. Please give proper link.

Comment: You should explain how to use the tool as well as the author's blog post is now 404.

Answer (score 5):

I use SQLyog:

[http://www.webyog.com/en/](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927075043/http://www.webyog.com/en/)

It isn't free but is a very good tool and has saved the cost of it's license many many times over.  I'm in no way affiliated with the company, just someone who has used a number of MySQL tools.

Free trial(30-day) available from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121013034925/http://www.webyog.com:80/en/downloads.php).

[image]

Comment: too bad it does not have Mac and Linux versions .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I was using SQLyog before on linux, on CentOS but it was thru WINE, I just don't know if it works now. I'm using an old version though.

Answer (score -9):

The best thing to do is to try out some performance benchmarks that are already out there.  It's always better to use tried-and-tested benchmarks, unless you're thoroughly convinced that your data and database loading is going to be significantly different to the traditional usage patterns (but, then, what are you using a database for?).  I'm going to steal [my own answer from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/219/how-do-you-choose-a-mysql-database-engine/232#232):

> There are a good number of benchmarks
>   out there for different MySQL database
>   engines. There's a decent one
>   comparing MyISAM, InnoDB and Falcon on
>   the [Percona MySQL Performance
>   Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/), see [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/).
>
> Another thing to consider between the
>   two aforementioned engines (MyISAM and
>   InnoDB) are their approaches to
>   locking. MyISAM performs
>   table-locking, whilst InnoDB performs
>   row-locking. There are a variety of
>   things to consider, not only downright
>   performance figures.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for benchmark tools.