# Compare database schema with MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench on my Windows 7 PC, and have a saved database model.

I am running MySQL on a Linux server.

Using MySQL Workbench's "Manage DB Connections", I am able to connect to MySQL running on the Linux server.

Using MySQL Workbench Community Edition, can I compare the MySQL Workbench model schema to the MySQL database schema running on the Linux server?  If so, how?

Comment: What is a "MySQL Workbench model schema"? The MySQL Workbench has no own schema. The schema is the one you've selected.

Comment: Seems like "Database/Synchronize Model might do it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://blog.webyog.com/2012/10/16/so-how-do-you-sync-your-database-schema/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you want is to reverse engineer a live database. Here's the manual entry on how to do it in mysql workbench.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html

Comment: @feeela - I'm just answering as best as I can with what's given... we'll see if I guessed right.

Comment: But how would I know what is changed?

Comment: @user1032531 - you would have to manually look at the two models. There's no way to get the "difference" between the two. I'm assuming you have a local model loaded and want to compare it to the live one correct?

Comment: @erik. Manually comparing the two models will be a horrendous task.  Tools exist such as those listed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876731/how-to-compare-mysql-database-schemas and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389468/compare-structures-of-two-databases, but I was hoping to use MySQL Workbench as I already know the tool.

Comment: @user1032531 - I see, well I've never come across any comparison tool in workbench. Perhaps it's there but I kinda doubt it. Best bet is probably to look into the tools you just linked to!

Comment: @Erik,  Have you used MySQL Workbench's Database/Synchronize Model or Compare and Report Differences in Catalog?  Both seem suggestive...